# Search data between age column

Tags: mysql

Below is my table structure. I want to select data between agemin column

```
ID       Age     PercenteM  Sex
1        18-24     0.0545    M
2        25-29     1.456     F
3        30-34     2.043     M
```

ie: `Select * from table where age = 28`

Comment: So the output is last 2 rows ?

Comment: i want to select * table where age = 28

Comment: How you can have `age = 28` ? You are saving the range which means none of the above row will be selected with age = 28 as lower limit. Is that correct ?

Comment: It would be better to make 2 collumns like: ageMin and ageMax and then use 'between'

Comment: @Simon how can write a query from 2 collumns please explain

Answer (score 2):

There are solutions to this, but they won't be pretty or easy to work with because of how your data is formatted.  As others have commented, you are better off splitting that column into two (age_min and age_max).  Essentially what you are trying to do will require that you break the number portions of your age column out.  Provided your formatting is consistent, you could do something like this.  I am assuming your intent, based on the query you wrote, was to return rows where the minimum age was 28.

```
Select * from table where substring_index(age, "-", 1)=28;
```

If you want all rows where your target age falls within the age range described, you will need a slightly different query.

```
Select * from table 
where substring_index(age, "-", 1)<=28 
and substring(age, locate("-")+1)>=28;
```

This will work with a smaller table, but will perform poorly if you are working with larger sets of data.

Comment: how can do this for larger set of data

Comment: Short answer is follow the advice other people have given.  The issue is that if your query has to break a column apart, it will have to perform a full table scan.  If you have a large number of rows you will have to split AGE into two columns - AGE_MIN and AGE_MAX.

Comment: can you please write a query for me when age is split into two columns

Comment: Select * from table where 28 between age_min and age_max;